# Routing with friendly URLs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

For example, I have an `About Us` page:

```
htttp://localhost/About/Index
```

How can I have an user-friendly URL for this page?

```
http://localhost/about-us.html
```

My current workaround:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AboutPage",
            template: "about-us.html",
            defaults: new {controller = "About", action = "Index"});
    });
}
```

This is the wrong way to do. How can I map routing correctly so that when I use `@Url.Action("Index", "About")` in cshtml page, it'll generate the link `/about-us.html` for me?

Comment: Why on earth should adding a ".html" extension make something _more_ user-friendly? To me, `http://example.org/about` would be the most user-friendly URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom URL like this:

```
[Route("about-us.html")]
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
    return Ok("About us");
}
```